# Como fazer um INSERT dentro do while

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá,

Como faço um INSERT dentro de um laço de repetição onde *id do comentário = id do comentário* olha o código

```
    $selecionarComentarios = $conexao->prepare("SELECT a.id_mark, a.id_user, a.comment, a.rate, a.id, a.active, b.name, b.avatar FROM tb_comment a, users b WHERE a.id_user=b.id AND a.id_mark = :post_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_pg, $amount_pg");
    $selecionarComentarios->bindParam(':post_id',$post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $selecionarComentarios->execute();

    if($selecionarComentarios->rowCount() > 0)
    {

        while ($show = $selecionarComentarios->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            $rating_user               = $show->rate;
            $idComment                   = $show->id;
            $dataComentario          = $show->active;
            $timestamp                   = strtotime($dataComentario);
            $avatarUser                  = $show->avatar;
            $idUsuarioComentario = $show->id_user;

            if (empty($avatarUser))
          {
            $avatarUser = "default/default.jpg";
          }

            $selecionarVotos = $conexao->prepare("SELECT b.id_user, b.id_mark, b.id, a.id_mark, a.id_comment, COUNT(a.vote) as votos FROM tb_comment_ud a, tb_comment b WHERE a.id_user=b.id_user AND a.id_mark = b.id_mark AND a.id_comment=:idComment");
            $selecionarVotos->bindParam(':idComment',$idComment, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $selecionarVotos->execute();

            if($selecionarVotos->rowCount() >= 1)
            {
                $mostrar = $selecionarVotos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $votos = $mostrar['votos'];
            }

            if(isset($_POST['comentarioLike']))
            {
                $inserirLikeComentario = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_comment_ud (id_user, id_mark, id_comment, vote, id_user_voting) VALUES (:idUsuarioComentario, :post_id, :idComment, 1, :idLogged)");
                $inserirLikeComentario->bindParam(':idUsuarioComentario',$idUsuarioComentario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $inserirLikeComentario->bindParam(':post_id',$post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $inserirLikeComentario->bindParam(':idComment',$idComment, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $inserirLikeComentario->bindParam(':idLogged',$idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                $procurarVotos = $conexao->prepare("SELECT b.id_user, b.id_mark, b.id, a.id_user, a.id_mark, a.id_comment, a.id_user_voting FROM tb_comment_ud a, tb_comment b
                    WHERE a.id_user=b.id_user AND a.id_mark = b.id_mark AND b.id=:idComment AND a.id_user_voting=:idLogged");
                $procurarVotos->bindParam(':idComment',$idComment, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $procurarVotos->bindParam(':idLogged',$idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $procurarVotos->execute();

                if($procurarVotos->rowCount() >= 1)
                {
                    echo "Voce ja votou";
                }
                else
                {
                    $inserirLikeComentario->execute();
                }
            }
```

Esse código funciona, ele insere tudo certinho só que ele insere varios registros, ele insere a quantidade de registros que tiver no SELECT *$selecionarComentarios*

Esse aqui é o código que está dentro do laço de repetição:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="on">
                    <button type="submit" name="comentarioLike" class="btn btn-secondary" aria-label="Útil"><span class="icon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
                    </form>
```

Meu objetivo é esse aqui, inserir 1 registro para cada usuario que clicar no botão de like que possui em cada comentário.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não estou no computador agora pra analisar vem o código as pelo que entendi, se o insert já está funcionando a única coisa a fazer é filtrar os comentários pelo Id no teu select. Ou então, só fazer insert caso o ID do comentários for igual ao id que tu mandou no post. Mas o certo seria inseri o like antes de começar a ler os comentários novamente.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver William?

Comment: @luigibertaco Sim, mais como faço isso eu tentei já e não consegui.. Tentei pelo WHERE no SELECT..

Comment: @durtto ainda não.

Comment: @luigibertaco Se eu colocar o like antes de começar a ler os comentario o insert vai sempre para o primeiro comentario

Comment: @luigibertaco Eu to deixando alguma coisa passar.. ctz D=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!!

Só troquei o _POST pela ID de cada comentário!!

```
$idComment = id de cada comentário

if(isset($_POST[$idComment]))
```

Comment: Marque a sua resposta como aceita então...